# Reference a local file (stored alongside node_modules) within Node.js with Environment Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

I have a Google credential file and AWS services that I need to use with a Node script on my laptop rather than the cloud. This has been previously set within AWS Lambda like so:

[image]

I am doing some testing on my Windows 10 laptop using Node.js 8.10 which is installed. How can I point or add environment variables for Node locally to point to the cred file?

[image]

How can I also add my AWS secret key on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mac or linux it would be like:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Google-3af068b12cb8.json node ./somescript.js`

for windows it's a bit more complicated. [This medium.com article](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786) covers it well.